# Call UITableView reloadSections method crashes

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview, reloaddata

I just do the normal operation: Request the data from the server and refresh the tableview by `reloadSections`, but I do get a lot of crash logs. If I call `reloadData`, everything is OK. Even though I known `reloadData` works well, it seems that `reloadSections` works more efficiently.
Does anybody have any ideas?

Get data from the server by persistent connection :

```
[_pomelo onRoute:@"onTlive" withCallback:^(NSDictionary *data) {
    @strongify(self);
    if (self.liveTableView) {
        [self.liveTableView configData:data refresh:self.playerView.isScreenPortrait];
    }
}];
```

Then config the data and refresh the tableview:

```
- (void)configData:(NSDictionary *)data refresh:(BOOL)refresh {
if (!data || data.allKeys.count == 0) {
    return;
}
NSArray *liveArray = [data valueForKeyPath:@"body.data"];
[liveArray enumerateObjectsUsingBlock:^(NSString *obj, NSUInteger idx, BOOL * _Nonnull stop) {
    NSArray *liveDetailInfo = [obj componentsSeparatedByString:@"|"];
    if (liveDetailInfo && liveDetailInfo.count > 0) {
        NSArray *tliveInfo = [liveDetailInfo.lastObject componentsSeparatedByString:@"^"];
        SPBasketballLive *liveObject = [SPBasketballLive new];
        liveObject.type = tliveInfo[0];
        liveObject.time = tliveInfo[1];
        liveObject.team = tliveInfo[2];
        liveObject.playerId = tliveInfo[3];
        liveObject.score = tliveInfo[4];
        liveObject.text = tliveInfo[5];
        liveObject.quarter = ((NSString *)liveDetailInfo.firstObject).integerValue;
        if (self.curMatch.liveInfo.count == liveObject.quarter) { 
            NSMutableArray *quarterArray  = self.curMatch.liveInfo.firstObject;
            [quarterArray insertObject:liveObject atIndex:0];
        } else { 
            NSMutableArray *quarterArray = [NSMutableArray new];
            [quarterArray addObject:liveObject];
            [self.curMatch.liveInfo insertObject:quarterArray atIndex:0];
        }
    }
}];
if (refresh) {
    if (_curMatch.liveInfo.count > 0) {
        [self.myTableView reloadSections:[NSIndexSet indexSetWithIndex:4] withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationNone];
    }
}
}
```

Here is the crash log:

> invalid update: invalid number of rows in section 4. The number of rows contained in an existing section after the update (98) must be equal to the number of rows contained in that section before the update (96), plus or minus the number of rows inserted or deleted from that section (0 inserted, 0 deleted) and plus or minus the number of rows moved into or out of that section (0 moved in, 0 moved out)

Comment: Please add some code here that you used for reloading the uitable.

Comment: what crash logs you getting please show here and make clear your requirements.

Answer (score 0):

Your app crashed because `reloadSection` method won't update section and row counters so it causes crashes in cases when you changed section or row counter and your `UITableView` have different counters.

And when  you use `reloadData` it first call `numberOfSectionsInTableView` and then `numberOfRowsInSection` is called so your `UITableView` has correct counters for sections and rows.

Comment: Er,but I make a demon that show when i call ````reloadSection````,the ````numberOfRowsInSection```` also run.

Comment: Does it called `numberOfSectionsInTableView `?

Comment: I'm sure that both  ````numberOfRowsInSection```` and ````numberOfSectionsInTableView```` runned.